# OBIEE Authentication using .Net

Tags: .net, adfs, obiee

I am trying to Authenticate OBIEE using .Net. I went through many examples where .Net code gets Authenticated by ADFS & then logs in to OBIEE. I do not want my Website to go to ADFS,inturn I want it to authenticate via C# code. I can successfully generate the ADFS token using C# but how can i forward the token to OBIEE now. or may be there is another way to do it.

Comment: What's the end game there? OBIEE is an analytical platform product and has a security backend the size of Canada. You can't just code your way into it any way you want. There are very explicit rules to it.

https://docs.oracle.com/middleware/12213/biee/BIESC/toc.htm

Comment: https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/tangent_thoughts/2015/02/20/install-and-configure-a-simple-net-4-5-sample-federated-application-samapp/               I followed this link.Kindly go through this if time permits and i would highly appreciate if you could be of some help.Thanks in advance....

Comment: You're not understanding what I am saying: Oracle BI is a huge product with clearly defined integration points for security.

THAT is what defines what's possible. Not how you want to come into it from the outside.

Comment: Getting logged in and Displaying OBIEE reports in to webforms is not a security issue i guess.wl share the screen and code once it has been done.By the way i didnt do it my own,  jst followed the documents mentioned.